# How to Get a scheduler (i.e) Particular Scheduler by Name in Quartz?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

i have created different schedulers with name such as sched1, sched2 etc.,

How to get a particular scheduler by name?

Ex: getScheduler("sched1"); -> need the sched1 instance

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,
Kathir

Comment: Could someone help me with the suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am missing some information about the context, how you build /start the scheduler, if you use spring ioc or anything similar, but anyway with the SchedulerFactory you have some method to get the Schedulers: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/SchedulerFactory.html#getScheduler(java.lang.String).

You can use a StdSchedulerFactory implementation for instance: 
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#StdSchedulerFactory(java.lang.String)

HIH